# HTML button dosen't call JavaScript-method

Tags: javascript, django

I have an HTML-button that a user can click to register an account:

```
<button onclick="redirectToHomePage()" class="ok-button" >
                Register</button>
```

Unfortunately, the JavaScript-method is never called. The strange thing is, when I replace the button with "input":

```
<input onclick="redirectToHomePage()" class="ok-button" >
                Register</input>
```

The method is called. So it works with "input", but not with "button". Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Edit: Some additional information, the button is inside a form:

```
<form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}

      <button onclick="redirectToHomePage()" class="ok-button">
      Register</button>
 </form>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is button inside a form?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. That's make it easier to investigate the issue.

Comment: that button is intended to do form submit right ?

Comment: That is correct itzMEonTV, and redirect to the home page!

Comment: Then why `redirectToHomePage` ?

Comment: I thought that it should post to a form, and then redirect to the home page, but maybe that is not the right way of doing it?

Comment: Ok. So you can do `HttpResponseRedirect("/url/")` from backend side. Keep this as button only

Comment: Your button is lacking a type attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

> ```
> type="button"
> ```

to button element.

Answer (score 0):

In your button tag, please use [type = "button"]

**HTML Code**

```
<button type="button" onclick="redirectToHomePage()" class="ok-button">
                Register</button>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
<script>
function redirectToHomePage(){
//code
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
function redirectToHomePage(){
alert('redirect to home page');
}
</script>
<form>
<button onclick="redirectToHomePage()" class="ok-button" >
                Register</button>
</form>

This code works for me. Maybe you haven't added tag into <form>
```

Comment: OP needs to redirect to another url after submit. This will not do that.

Comment: Yes. if you want to redirect to another URL you need to add type="button". If we don't define type, by default it takes submit type. Another option is simply adding action to <form>.